# Problmen in Binding ASP Chart Y Axis labels

Tags: asp.net, charts

I'm working with asp bar chart.

i want to display user data with percentage of sales like user1 26%, User2 45%...

when i bind data to chart, names and data bars displaying properly. 
but percentages on Y axis labels not properly displaying.

i have tried below properties for Axis Y

```
Maximum="100" 
Minimum="0" 
Interval="10" 
Format="0,%"
```

it is showing 1%,2%,3%...10%

my intention is to show 0%, 10%, 20%, 30% etc... 100%

Answer (score 1):

Please use this in label style Format="{0#}%"